# .NET 5, Create WebService with consume an API

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I have to post data in URL "myurl/api/shipment"

I created a simple .NET 5 Webapi project to post data with swagger.
component created on the project are : Model (shipment.cs), Service (ApiService.cs) and a Controller.
Headers must contain two parameters

> ("Content-Type : text/html", "api_key : ")

NB : The API key is generated in the get method by consuming the URL "https://portail.ctm-messagerie.com/api/token" with parameters ("Content-Type", "text/html","username", "CIH CARTES","password", "*************") and it work on my project

This is my service (ApiService.cs) :

```
//Get method ("Content-Type", "text/html","username", "CIH CARTES","password", "*************")
public async Task<string> GetTokenAsync()
{
    var url = "url/api/token";
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Content-Type", "text/html"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "CIH CARTES"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "**********")
    });

    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var token = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return token;
    }

    return null;
}
```

```
//Post method 
public async Task<string> PostShipmentAsync(Shipment shipment, string token)
{
    var url = "myurl/api/shipment";

    var jsonContent = JsonSerializer.Serialize(shipment);

    var content = new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("api_key", token);//string token

    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return result;
    }

    return null;
}
```

and here my controller :

[image]

I post data with RESTED extension in Google Chrome works!

[image]

but in swagger tested in my project I got message below:

[image]

The expecting return is to get this message:

[image]

Comment: [You should not post code (or errors/exceptions, logs, configuration, project files, or anything else that is represented in textual form) as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)